# Android.mk rules to make a file.o from many files.txt then link it with other files.o produced from files.cpp

Tags: android, build, makefile

I'm porting a modem connection manager written in C++ from linux to gingerbread. This does not end up being an "app" with a "gui" that I would use a java wrapper with the NDK but a service that is called at boot from "init.rc". I found some not up to date docs related to android build system under build/core/. There you find some html files explaining the basics of Android build system and several "file.mk" which are some templates for common situation like creating a c++ executable, static libraries, shared library etc.

I place my tree with all the sources under external/myservice and it's meant to be compiled at the same time as Android itself. (I've already ported the kernel to my platform and it works, just the modem left to go)

In a subfolder in an Android.mk file, I have a bunch of ".cpp" files listed with the variable LOCAL_SRC_FILES := cppfile1.cpp cppfile2.cpp ....  That will generate cppfile1.o cppfile2.o ...

I need to link those cppfile*.o with objfile.o to form a libfile.so. I found the rules on how to generate a libfile.so from a bunch of files.o.

Where things get complicated, is to port the "linux makefile" command to create objfile.o. Here is how it looks like

> ```
> $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -r -b binary -o QMIDB.o \  
>             QMI/Entity.txt \  
>             QMI/EnumEntry.txt \  
>             QMI/Enum.txt \  
>             QMI/Field.txt \  
>             QMI/Struct.txt
> ```

Which means it is a linker job to merge a bunch of text file to make that objfile.o. That file is just a bunch of initialized data structure, there is no code to execute in it but it's pretty ugly to look at all files.txt with a text editor.

I have no clue how to integrate that in the Android.mk file. How can it be done? I'd even appreciate just a hint on where I can find more information. It is easy to find information on building Android applications but it's another story to find anything closer to Android/Kernel itself.

Answer (score 0):

From the mk. file file you can easily get so file....

You need to use android Ndk setup and cygwin setup if you are using windows platform to genreate so file from your native code.

Firstly install and place ndk to a location...

Then install cygwin setup not default one check all features in the installation process (it a sort of linux terminal) as ndk-build command is recognized from linux terminal.

Now from your cygwin terminal get access to your project folder jni file.. or where mk is placed...

```
http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html
```

Use the following referal how to run ndk-build command from cygwin terminal..

Now providing complete path of ndk we use the ndk-build command...

After that the complied code generates the .so file for our project...

Now what we are using System.loadlibrary command to use the so file i.e our native code can now be used.

**Note to get so file form mk we need to complie using ndk setup.We can't directly copy paste so file to make our native code run.Also we we are using windows platfrom we will need to use cygwin setup to do that**

Comment: Thanks Arpit for the info. I already found how to generate de "file.so".  My real problem is how to generate the objfile.o from the "files.txt" as per the Makefile command shown in my question.

Comment: To be more precise is that I don't want to generate an Android Application in which case I need the NDK to compile C/C++ code. What I'm doing is under Dalvik and will be included in Android, at least the port that I'm doing for my platform. There is already C/C++ code in Android and it doesn't use the NDK to compile it.